# Alteryx a good ETL Tool

Tags: powerbi, hiveql

Is Alteryx a Hadoop Data Ware House Tool or ETL process tool. My Company is looking for a Replacement for the built-in Hive Tools.

Comment: What is your exact problem? It claims to be an ETL tool from there website: `Flip the 80/20 data prep rule upside down. Unlock all your datasets - big or small, clean or dirty. No waiting. No coding. Connect, profile, prep, and blend all your data, wherever it's stored. Data scientists and citizen users alike can create powerful statistical, predictive, prescriptive, and spatial models, whether that’s in a code-free workflow.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes and a really great one if your data analyts don't know how to or don't want to write code. It's all wysiwyg, using a visio-like flowchart of objects that can be configured to do all you ETL. In many cases, it's outpaced many languages in terms of being able to do traditional ETL, predictive analytics, etc...

The only bad side of Alteryx I would say is that it's server product isn't a great job scheduler the way other job-based queue systems work.

Answer (score 0):

Alteryx is a data preparation (dataprep) tool, not an ETL.

That means, if the result can be the same (a table^^), the way to create is simpler and "functionnaly" oriented.

For Hive, you have in-db tools that makes the job... but not perfectly. I had to develop some macro to get exactly what I wanted (storage in orc+statistics+ datastream in with textfile is an example of missing feature you can add with macro).

The best thing with Alteryx is that it's really easy to use and configure.